# Div height: 100% not working with body min-height: 100vh

Tags: html, css

I encountered what for me is an unexpected behaviour. I wanted to set the `body` min-height to the height of the viewport (100vh), then make a `div` (with the class of container) inside it that would take the whole height of the body (100%), so that the div would extend at least to all of the height of the viewport. Except that this doesn't happen; the only way to achieve this result is to set `html` and `body` height to 100%. What's the technical reason that makes this this happen? Shouldn't the div take the (min-)height of 100% of its parent anyway?

[Here you can find a codepen with the expected behaviour commented out at the end of the css](https://codepen.io/mpasquato/pen/qBrmxVm)

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #ddd;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  background: #aaa;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Uncomment for the expected behaviour */
/*
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Some generic title</h1>
  <p>Some random paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Just lost an hour on this same problem. I hate CSS.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The answer is simple as percentage `min-height` is calculated based on parent container's `height` value not `min-height`.

```css
* {margin:0;}

body {
  background: gray;
  height: 100vh; /* look here */
}

.container {
  background: silver;
  margin: 0 20px;
  min-height: 100%;  /* look here */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Some generic title</h1>
  <p>Some random paragraph</p>
</div>
```

But, with `min-height:inherit` it then inherits the `min-height` value from the parent container.

```css
* {margin:0;}

body {
  background: gray;
  min-height: 100vh; /* look here */
}

.container {
  background: silver;
  margin: 0 20px;
  min-height: inherit;  /* look here */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Some generic title</h1>
  <p>Some random paragraph</p>
</div>
```

I would set `min-height:100%` on `.container` directly if it always covers the viewport height.

```css
* {margin:0;}

body {
  background: gray;
}

.container {
  background: silver;
  margin: 0 20px;
  min-height: 100vh; /* look here */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1>Some generic title</h1>
  <p>Some random paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: This cleared up my mind, I assumed that the height of the child depended on the actual value of the height calculated on the fly. Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1):

this does the magic for me. the idea is min-height is 100vh or 100% in case content is larger than 100vh.

```css
body {
  background: gray;
  height: max-content; 
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  background: silver;
  margin: 0 20px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*,
*::after,
*::before {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background: #ddd;
  min-height: 100vh;
  height: 100vh;
}

.container {
  background: #aaa;
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 1rem;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

/* Uncomment for the expected behaviour */
/*
html,
body {
  height: 100%
}
*/
```

```html
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Some generic title</h1>
    <p>Some random paragraph</p>
  </div>
```